# How to use external files as resources in multidomain environment on wildfly

Tags: java, resources, external, wildfly, multiple-domains

I have following configuration:

- Wildfly 8.1.0
- multi-domain environment
- in each domain I've deployed the same EAR, but with different INI files
- EAR contains Configuration.jar with config.ini file and RestWS.war with WEB-INF/classes/shiro.ini

I would like to protect these INI files from overwriting. Is it possible to specify external files instead of these from EAR?

Comment: What do you mean by "multi-domain environment"? Do you mean you have many server groups?

Answer (score 0):

The article [How to put an external file in the classpath](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath) describes how to do this.